# JasperReports including blank page at the end of the PDF

Tags: java, jasper-reports, ireport

I'm generating a PDF using JasperReports from Java. I finally succeeded in making Jasper correctly paginate the report. The problem is that now I'm getting a blank page at the end of the report (the headers are printed, but the detail band is blank). The information passed for the detail band is all displayed, so there is no need for that page (what is more, there is an empty space at the end of the last page). I will attach the JXML at the end of the question, any help appreciated.

Thanks!

This is the content of the JXML file:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="tintoreria" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="555" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" isFloatColumnFooter="true">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.0"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="0"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="288"/>
    <parameter name="SUBREPORT_DIR" class="java.lang.String" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression><![CDATA["C:\\work\\REPO-CTK\\lasastra-world\\core\\src\\main\\resources\\jasper\\tintoreria\\"]]></defaultValueExpression>
    </parameter>
    <parameter name="totalItems" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="nroPag" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="totalPag" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="supplier" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="creationDate" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="orderNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="fechaPedido" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <parameter name="datasourceParam" class="net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <pageHeader>
        <band height="119" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle radius="10">
                <reportElement x="0" y="0" width="555" height="119" backcolor="#CCCCFF"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="112" y="7" width="241" height="32"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="24" isBold="true" isUnderline="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Orden de compra]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="286" y="62" width="63" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Proveedor:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="355" y="62" width="189" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{supplier}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="281" y="42" width="72" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Orden Nro:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="355" y="42" width="189" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{orderNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="268" y="83" width="85" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Fecha Pedido:]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="355" y="83" width="189" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$P{creationDate}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="633" splitType="Stretch">
            <subreport runToBottom="false">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" stretchType="RelativeToBandHeight" mode="Transparent" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="633" isRemoveLineWhenBlank="true" isPrintInFirstWholeBand="true"/>
                <dataSourceExpression><![CDATA[$P{datasourceParam}]]></dataSourceExpression>
                <subreportExpression><![CDATA["purchaseorder_subreport1.jasper"]]></subreportExpression>
            </subreport>
        </band>
    </detail>
    <pageFooter>
        <band height="50" splitType="Stretch">
            <rectangle radius="10">
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="0" y="0" width="555" height="50" backcolor="#CCCCFF"/>
                <graphicElement>
                    <pen lineWidth="1.75"/>
                </graphicElement>
            </rectangle>
            <textField>
                <reportElement positionType="Float" x="22" y="15" width="239" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="13"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Cantidad de items: " + $P{totalItems}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="331" y="25" width="159" height="20"/>
                <textElement textAlignment="Right"/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA["Pagina  "+$V{PAGE_NUMBER}+" de "]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField evaluationTime="Report">
                <reportElement x="490" y="25" width="40" height="20"/>
                <textElement/>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[" " + $V{PAGE_NUMBER}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </pageFooter>
</jasperReport>
```

And this is the subreport:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="tintoreria_subreport1" pageWidth="540" pageHeight="600" whenNoDataType="NoDataSection" columnWidth="540" leftMargin="0" rightMargin="0" topMargin="0" bottomMargin="0" isFloatColumnFooter="true" whenResourceMissingType="Empty">
    <property name="ireport.zoom" value="1.5394743546921208"/>
    <property name="ireport.x" value="131"/>
    <property name="ireport.y" value="0"/>
    <queryString>
        <![CDATA[]]>
    </queryString>
    <field name="itemNumber" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <field name="amount" class="java.lang.String"/>
    <columnHeader>
        <band height="22" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="1" y="1" width="68" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Item]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="76" y="1" width="373" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[   Descripción]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="69" y="1" width="1" height="21"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="0" y="21" width="540" height="1"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="448" y="0" width="1" height="21"/>
            </line>
            <staticText>
                <reportElement x="453" y="1" width="68" height="20"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="12" isBold="true"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Cantidad]]></text>
            </staticText>
        </band>
    </columnHeader>
    <detail>
        <band height="13" splitType="Stretch">
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="1" y="0" width="68" height="12"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{itemNumber}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="77" y="0" width="371" height="12"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{description}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="69" y="0" width="1" height="13"/>
            </line>
            <line>
                <reportElement x="448" y="0" width="1" height="13"/>
            </line>
            <textField>
                <reportElement x="453" y="1" width="75" height="12"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="9"/>
                </textElement>
                <textFieldExpression><![CDATA[$F{amount}]]></textFieldExpression>
            </textField>
        </band>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

Comment: were you ever able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You should manually hide the bands after `Detail`.
For example try hiding the `Summary` band by setting it's `Print When Expression` to `Boolean.FALSE`

```
<summary>
     <band height="1" splitType="Stretch">
           <printWhenExpression><![CDATA[Boolean.FALSE]]></printWhenExpression>
     </band>
</summary>
```

Note: not sure about the exact XML context, since I usually do it in iReport.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have deleted all the bands from the document at iReport and only left Page Header, Detail and Page Footer. And at the subreport just Column Header and Detail, so I don't think that should resolve the problem, but I'll try.

Comment: This did solve my problem where I was getting supurious extra pages in some of my reports (and sub-reports).

Comment: This solves the issue, but it also does not display the page if the data is present there. How to check if data exists?

Answer (score 6):

I faced this issue, in my case it is solved by:

1. Go to Report Properties.
2. Then check Ignore Pagination property.

That's it. I hope it helps.

Comment: Worked for me too, in my case I had only the title band with a list that for some reason print an extra page

Comment: While this approach solves the issue with extra blank page, I have noticed a drawback: if height of the content goes beyond assigned page height, the page just gets longer. This might be an issue if report is intended for printing on standard paper (A4, Letter, etc.)

Comment: That should be used when the report is intended to be printed on continous paper. It's not a proper fix.

Answer (score 2):

This issue may be due to empty space in report, In jasper there is a setting if you right click a band it says "Strectch to contents",click it